# Is there a one trigger latch for AC?

Tags: latch, scr

SCR is good for latching DC source, one trigger will turn on the source indefinitely. But how about AC source?

Latching mechanical relays is good but it is too big for me. Triac is designed for AC but not good for me as the triac must be triggered every time. Is there an electronic component or circuit design that can latch AC source with one trigger (SCR but designed for AC source)?

For example, I made a project before, just a simple motion sensor powered by 5V battery. If the module sense something, it will interrupt MCU which will then trigger the latching relay once to open the light bulb connected to main AC line, but the latching relay made it look big and I don't like it. I want it similar to latching DC in which just a single SCR will latch the source with one trigger and so saves battery power and is smaller compared to relay.

Comment: Please describe the use case of the desired circuit/component in a bit more detail; as it will help us making a more qualified guess on what you are trying to accomplish:)

Comment: I added something just now